# Can there be a matrix $M$ such that $M^n\ne0$, but $M^{2n}=0$ for some integer $n>1$?

Tags: matrices, exponentiation

Reading about [dual numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number), which can be modeled by a matrix $\varepsilon$ such that $\varepsilon^2=0$, I wonder if it could be generalized to something which gives nonzero square, but e.g. a zero after some $n$ repeated squarings. Namely, I'm interested in a matrix model, so that it'd be easy to experiment with.

Do such matrices $M$ exist, that for some integer $n>1$ we had $M^n\ne0$, but $M^{2n}=0$? If yes, how to construct them?

Comment: Is there a size requirement on the matrix? If not, then the answer is yes.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi no requirement other than it has to be finite.

Comment: Also, what should happen between $n$ and $2n$? Is $M^{n+1} = 0$ acceptable?

Comment: Yes, it'd be OK I think.

Comment: Take any $ n \times n $ matrix with 1's above the diagonal. Then $ M^k \ne 0 $ for $ k < n $, while $ M^n = 0 $.

Comment: Wow, that's quite interesting. Could you make an answer with this?

Comment: Sure thing, I'll elaborate a bit more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an entire class of matrices that have this property. Consider for instance the $ 4 \times 4 $ matrix
$$
M = \begin{pmatrix}0 & a & b & c\\0 & 0 & d & e\\0 & 0 & 0 & f\\0 & 0 & 0 &0\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Let $ a, d, f \ne 0 $ to simplify the discussion. Then you can work out that $ M^k \ne 0 $ for $ k < 4 $, whereas $ M^4 = 0 $ for any choice of the matrix elements.
This can be generalized to square matrices of any given dimension. Such matrices are said to be [strictly upper triangular](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StrictlyUpperTriangularMatrix.html).

Now, I won't claim this is the most general form of a nilpotent matrix, but it's a quite large class to begin with.

Comment: As far as I remember, any nilpotent matrix is similar to a strictly upper triangular one, FYI.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Yes, I think you are right. Any square matrix (at least, those over $ \mathbb R $) can be reduced to its Jordan normal form, and combining this with the requirement that $ \mathrm{Tr} M = 0 $ (necessary for $ M $ to be nilpotent, as its eigenvalues need be all 0's) you get that $ M $ can be arranged in this form. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

In one picture: $$\begin{pmatrix}0&0&\color{red}{\bf1}&0&0&0&\cdots&\cdots&0\\ 0&0&0&\color{red}{\bf1}&0&0&\cdots&\cdots&0\\ 0&0&0&0&\color{red}{\bf1}&0&\cdots&\cdots&0\\ 0&0&0&0&0&\color{red}{\bf1}&\cdots&\cdots&0\\ 0&0&0&0&0&0&\cdots&\cdots&0\\ \vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots\\ 0&0&0&0&0&0&\cdots&\cdots&\color{red}{\bf1}\\ 0&0&0&0&0&0&\cdots&\cdots&0\\ 0&0&0&0&0&0&\cdots&\cdots&0\end{pmatrix}\qquad (i=2,d\geqslant3)$$
In more than one word:

Fix a vector basis $(e_k)_{1\leqslant k\leqslant d}$ of $\mathbb R^d$, where $d$ is the size of $M$, and some $1\leqslant i\leqslant d-1$, and assume that $Me_k=e_{k-i}$ for every $i+1\leqslant k\leqslant d$ and $Me_k=0$ for every $1\leqslant k\leqslant i$.

The corresponding matrices are $M=(M_{k,\ell})_{1\leqslant k,\ell\leqslant d}$ where $M_{k,\ell}=0$ for every $(k,\ell)$ except $M_{k,k+i}=1$ for every $1\leqslant k\leqslant d-i$. If $i=1$, these are known as (nilpotent) [Jordan matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_matrix).

Then, for every $n\geqslant0$, $$M^n=0\iff ni\geqslant d.$$
Thus, $$M^n\ne0=M^{2n}\iff \frac{d}{2n}\leqslant i\lt \frac{d}n.$$

Note finally the restriction that if $M^m=0$ for some $m$ then $M^d=0$, thus $M^{2n}=0\ne M^n$ is impossible if $d\leqslant n$.

Comment: You might find this useful: `(\vdots)` gives $(\vdots)$ and `(\ddots)` gives $(\ddots)$ (there's also `\iddots` but it doesn't work in mathjax).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Thanks.