# How to find a matrix $Y$ with $Y^2≠0$ while $Y^3=0$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm asked to find a $3\times3$ matrix $Y$ where $Y^2≠0$ while $Y^3=0$.

May I ask is there any method to solve such a question?

thank you!

Comment: Any such matrix must have all eigenvalues zero. If $Y$ is such a matrix, then so is $J$, the Jordan form of $Y$. Now there are not too many choices for the Jordan form of a $3\times3$ matrix with all eigenvalues zero. So, that's a method.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1019816/can-there-be-a-matrix-m-such-that-mn-ne0-but-m2n-0-for-some-integer

Answer (score 2):

Since you are asking for a method, not for an example, here's something more general. You are given a monic polynomial $P=X^3$ of degree $d=3$, and asked to construct a matrix $A$ such that substituting it into $P$ gives the zero matrix: $P[A]=0$, but the same does not hold for any lower degree nonzero polynomial. If this is the case then $P$ is called the minimal polynomial for $A$ (every matrix has one).

A systematic way to solve this is imagine a nonzero vector $v$ and to assume that $v,Av,A^2v,\ldots,A^{d-1}v$ form a basis of the vector space; this insures that any nonzero polynomial $Q$ with $\deg Q<d$ will have $Q[A]v\neq0$, so certainly $Q[A]\neq0$. In fact you can start out with a basis, and make $A$ map each non-final basis vector to the next basis vector. That leaves the image by$~A$ of the final basis vector $A^{d-1}v$ free to choose. That image will become $A^dv$. If we split off the first term of $P$, so $P=X^d+R$ with $\deg R<d$, then the requirement $P[A]v=0$ gives $A^dv=-R[A]v$, and the right hand side is a specific linear combination of $v,Av,A^2v,\ldots,A^{d-1}v$. So we can set image by$~A$ of $A^{d-1}$ to be that linear combination.

It may seem that this only ensures $P[A]v=0$ rather than $P[A]=0$. However, every vector$~w$ can be written as $w=Q[A]v$ for some polynomial $Q$ (which can be chosen of degree${}<d$); then $P[A]w=P[A](Q[A]v)=(PQ)[A]v$ since composition of polynomials in $A$ corresponds to multiplication of polynomials; since the latter operation is commutative, one can further rewrite the expression as $Q[A](P[A]v)=Q[A]0=0$. So $P[A]w=0$ for all vectors $w$, whence $P[A]=0$.

If $P=c_0+c_1X+\cdots+c_{d-1}X^{d-1}+X^d$, then $-R[A]v=-c_0v-c_1Av-\cdots-c_{d-1}A^{d-1}v$, so the final column of the matrix has entries $-c_0,-c_1,\ldots,-c_{d-1}$ and the whole matrix is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & -c_0 \\
1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & -c_1 \\
0 & 1 & \dots & 0 & -c_2 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \dots & 1 & -c_{d-1}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
This is the [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) of $P$, which is the standard example of a matrix with minimal polynomial$~P$.

This method builds a square matrix of size$~d$, and this is indeed the minimal size necessary for an example. In your question $d=3$ and $R=0$, so you get the matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:
$$Y=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.$$

The general idea is that of a [nilpotent matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent_matrix).

Answer (score 0):

The [companion matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) defined as $M=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\1&0&0\\0&1&0 \end{pmatrix}$ meets the requirements: $M^2=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\1&0&0\end{pmatrix},$ and $M^3=0.$
In fact, for any polynomial $p,$ the companion matrix of $p$ has minimal polynomial equal to $p.$
Hope this helps.